# Formula in english

Tags: logic

Consider:

A: I eat
B: I drink

I have this formula

`¬A ⇒ ¬B`

plain English translation: I do not eat if I do not drink.

I have tried to rewritten the formula as follows:

`¬ (A ⇒ B) = A ∧ ¬B`

English translation
I ate and I did not drink.

Could it be ?

`It is not the case that I ate if I did not drink.`

Or

`I did not eat implies; I did drink.` -> this one doesn't seem to be proper English.

I think my assumptions of rewriting the formula are wrong?

Note: This post has been updated

Comment: The initial statement, "$\neg A\implies \neg B$",  means "If I did not eat then I did not drink".  If you did eat, then the statement is silent.  Perhaps you drank and perhaps you did not drink.  We can't tell from the statement.

Comment: "¬A ⇒ ¬B can also be rewritten as ¬ (A ⇒ B) = A ∧ ¬B" No. $\neg A \implies \neg B$ is logically equivalent to $B \implies A$, but this is not equivalent to $\neg(A \implies B)$.

Answer (score 1):

The literal translation of $\neg A \implies \neg B$ is just "If I don't eat, I don't drink." (There is no past tense in the initial translation keys you provided.)

$\neg A \implies \neg B$ is the logically equivalent contraposition of $B \implies A$, so you could also translate the statement as "If I drink, I eat".

And since $B \implies A$ can in turn be rewritten as $\neg B \lor A$ and $\neg (B \land \neg A)$, you could also say "Either I don't drink or I eat", or "It's not the case that I drink but don't eat".

IMO "If I drink, I eat" is the most natural paraphrase.